# Dispatcher не запускает метод в нужном потоке

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

У меня есть WPF окно, по событию которого вызывается комманда ViewModel. Она в свою очередь вызывает метод из BAL, запускающий дочерний поток(может жить от 10 сек до бесконечности). Данный поток генерирует события по мере выполнения и еще одно событие в самом конце, извещающее о конце работы. Тк события происходят не основном потоке, то ViewModel использует Dispatcher для синхронизации. Если я что-то на проектировал не так, буду рад узнать.
Для выполнения кода в нужном потоке я использую следующий код

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(SomeMethod));
```

Но этот код не вызывает мне нужный метод в обще. Далее я попробовал вызвать следующий код

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(SomeMethod));
```

В итоге я все равно получил ошибку, тк выполнение не в главном потоке.
Тестирования ради я объявил поле _dispatcher и инициализировал его в конструкторе в время работы главного потока. Данный диспетчер мне уже все спокойно вызывал.
С чем это связано и как мне быть? Если я вдруг создам ViewModel не в главном потоке, то у меня опять работать ничего не будет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотрите.

`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` возвращает вам диспетчер для *данного потока*. Поэтому у вас нету альтернативы хранению ссылки на диспетчер.

Затем, VM-объекты обязаны бежать в UI-потоке (иначе вы не сможете биндить к ним View), так что они должны конструироваться тоже в UI-потоке. А значит, вы вполне можете рассчитывать на то, что уж в конструкторе у вас будет правильный `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`.

---

Почему не работает диспетчер, созданный в фоновом потоке? Диспетчер — это абстракция над циклом сообщений. Если в данном потоке бежит цикл сообщений, то `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` его вам и возвращает. Если же для данного потока диспетчера нету, создаётся новый и прикрепляется к данному потоку. Но этот диспетчер ещё не запущен! Команда лежит в очереди и дожидается. Если вы запустите диспетчер в фоновом потоке, то все команды, отосланные ему, будут выполнены.

Однако, не пытайтесь сделать это в потоке из пула потоков: для работы диспетчера поток должен быть STA, а потоки из пула — не STA (и это нельзя поменять).

Ну и по-хорошему обычно вам должно хватать диспетчера в UI-потоке.

Comment: А если я сделаю класс BaseViewModel имеющий статическое поле _dispatcher и статический конструктор, который его инициализирует. Как этот вариант?

Comment: @Nodon: По идее можно. Тут к сожалению есть шанс, что какой-то посторонний поток попробует обратиться к какому-нибудь статическому полю `BaseViewModel` (например, к тому же `_dispatcher`), и тем самым нечаянно запустить статический конструктор не в том потоке. (Проблем с доступом к _нестатическому_ полю нет, т. к. для доступа к нему VM-объект уже будет сконструирован.) Если ваша архитектура гарантирует отсутствие этой проблемы, почему бы и не сделать так.